# Pytesseract works in Visual Studio Code but not in Pycharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, tesseract

im using Ubuntu 22.04 and I have installed

```
tesseract --version
tesseract 5.2.0
 leptonica-1.82.0
  libgif 5.2.1 : libjpeg 9e : libpng 1.6.39 : libtiff 4.5.1 : zlib 1.2.13 : libwebp 1.2.4 : libopenjp2 2.4.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE4.1
 Found OpenMP 201511
 Found libarchive 3.6.2 zlib/1.2.13 liblzma/5.4.2 bz2lib/1.0.8 liblz4/1.9.4 libzstd/1.5.2
```

In my conda Python 3.11 env.
So im using the same environment on VSCode and I can run

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.get_languages()
```

but the same code on the same env does not run on Pycharm.
Does someone know why?

Error

```
TesseractNotFoundError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 pytesseract.get_languages()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pdfextractor/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py:146, in run_once.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    143 @wraps(func)
    144 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    145     if wrapper._result is wrapper:
--> 146         wrapper._result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    147     return wrapper._result

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pdfextractor/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py:370, in get_languages(config)
    368 # tesseract 3.x
    369 if result.returncode not in (0, 1):
--> 370     raise TesseractNotFoundError()
    372 languages = []
    373 if result.stdout:

TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

Regards

Comment: Check your VSCode settings, whether there are additional environmental settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can help pytesseract to find the path, if you add a line such as:

```
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

Pleas adjust the path according your installation directory.